# Homogeneous polynomial map inducing diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f(x) = (p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x))$ is a homogeneous polynomial inducing a diffeomorphic mapping of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ onto itself. Homegeneous means $f(tx)=t^n f(x)$, for $t>0$ and some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.  Why $n$ should be 1?

Comment: $f(x)=(x_1^3,x_2^3,x_3^3)$ is counterexample.

Comment: @YCor. This is not a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$ onto itself. Its Jacobian is $3^3x_1^2 x_2^2 x_3^2=0$ not only on $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks, you're right... sorry! I'm leaving it for other users...

Answer (score 14):

$f(x)= |x|^2 x$ is a counterexample?

Comment: That's not a polynomial.

Comment: @ZachTeitler I think it is - $|x|^2 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Oh right! Thanks.

Comment: @KevinCasto: Isn't the Jacobian $3(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3$?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki oops you're right!

Comment: Note: the inverse diffeomorphism is given by $x\mapsto |x|^{-2/3}x$.